# Arraylist - Separate a string and put it into an array

Tags: c#

I want to separate a string and put it into an array.

Example:

```
id = 12,32,544,877,136,987 

arraylist: [0]-->12
           [1]-->32
           [2]--544
           [3]-->877
           [4]-->136
           [5]-->987
```

How to do that?

Comment: I just want to trim the string where the "," is and pass it to the arraylist so i can return the last index for my program :)

Comment: This question is so basic and was asked 1000 times. Why you use an `ArrayList` at all if you are new to the language? Use a generic `List<string>`.

Comment: is there a particular reason for the choice of an [ArrayList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) ??? Might it be that this is homework? and the `ArrayList` a prerequesite of the excercise?

Comment: `ArrayList`'s origin was back then when a `List<T>` didnt exist yet. I suggest you to go with a `List<T>`, since it provides advantages that an `ArrayList` can offer.

Answer (score 1):

If your id var is a String, you can use the Split method:

```
id.Split(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
string[] arraylist = id.Split(',');
```

Answer (score 1):

Can do something like this in java :

```
   ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList <String>();

   String id = "12,32,544,877,136,987";

   String idArr[] = id.split(",");
   for(String idVal: idArr){
       idList.add(idVal);
   }
```